# Using fetch to call the OpenAi API throws error 400 "you must provide a model parameter"

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, openai-api

Followed the OpenAI API docs and but there is something wrong with this POST request... I get an "you must provide a model parameter" error ... what is wrong with the request body?

````
try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`,
            {
                body: JSON.stringify({"model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": "Say this is a test", "temperature": 0, "max_tokens": 7}),
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer [API-KEY]",
                },
                    }
        ).then((response) => {
            if (response.ok) {
                response.json().then((json) => {
                    terminal.echo(json);
                });
            }
        });
      
        console.log("Completed!");
    } catch (err) { console.error(`Error: ${err}`) }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [API Reference](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) a valid request looks like this:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY' \
  -d '{
  "model": "text-davinci-003",
  "prompt": "Say this is a test",
  "max_tokens": 7,
  "temperature": 0
}'
```

We can see that `model` is passed as a property in the request body. The request body has to be a JSON string. Additionally, the API requires two request headers: `content-type` and `authorization`.

The request body shared in your example is correct. The `authorization` request header is also there. However, the `content-type` header is missing in your example as it was - apparently and probably mistakenly - replaced by the `accept` header.

Due to the missing `content-type` header, the API does not know what content type the request body body has (could be json, yaml, xml, etc..). The API therefore, cannot process the request body and responds with the fact that the model parameter is missing.

The following example works in Chrome:

```
    await fetch(
        `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`,
        {
            body: JSON.stringify({"model": "text-davinci-003", "prompt": "Say this is a test", "temperature": 0, "max_tokens": 7}),
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json",
                Authorization: "Bearer  API_KEY_HERE",
            },
                }
    ).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then((json) => {
                terminal.echo(json);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const endpointUrl_Turbo = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
    var apiKey = "";
    var userPrompt="";
  
    await fetch(
       endpointUrl_Turbo,
    {
        body: JSON.stringify({"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", 
         "messages": [
            {
              role: "system",
              content: userPrompt,            
            },
            {
              role: "user",
              content: "You are a helpful assistant. Given the context, 
provide answers to the questions.",            
            },
          ], 
        "temperature": 0,
        "max_tokens":500}),
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer "+ apiKey_Turbo,
        },
            }
).then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
        response.json().then((json) => {           
            console.log(json['choices'][0]['message']['content']);         
          });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).